# Displaying time in real-time and updating within a listview

Tags: java, android, android-handler

What is the best way to display the time and update it constantly within a TextView? The code that I currently have does not update the existing TextView but rather it creates a new TextView inside of my layout [Example](http://puu.sh/j6gyp/265af28216.png).

I have the following codes: [Boss.java](http://paste.ofcode.org/GMVayAgUjczgDEBvtWuc8X) [BossAdapter.java](http://paste.ofcode.org/CiWJnc9ZGidTRefuNhbKeb)

```
public String[] getTime(){

    String[] time_array = new String[6];
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH-mm-ss");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        time_array[i] = formattedDate;
    }

    return time_array;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    bossView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boss_time);
    boss_title = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.boss_array);
    adapter = new BossAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.boss_layout);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    handler = new Handler();
    Runnable update = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            bossTime = getTime();
            int i = 0;
            for (String boss : boss_title) {
                Boss bossObject = new Boss(boss_icon[i], boss, bossTime[i]);
                adapter.add(bossObject);
                i++;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this , 1000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(update, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, code fixes are commented and explained below,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    bossView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boss_time);
    boss_title = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.boss_array);
    adapter = new BossAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.boss_layout);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    bossTime = getTime();
    int i = 0;
    // Moved our object creation here, so that it should only be done once.
    for (String boss : boss_title) {
        Boss bossObject = new Boss(boss_icon[i], boss, bossTime[i]);
        adapter.add(bossObject);
        i++;
    }

    handler = new Handler();
    Runnable update = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bossTime = getTime();
            int count = adapter.getCount()
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                ((Boss) adapter.getItem(i)).setBoss_time(bossTime[i]); // Re-set time
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify our update
            handler.postDelayed(this , 1000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(update, 10);
}
```

Comment: I have attempted this however the line "((Boss) adapter.getItem(i)).setBoss_time(i);" does not work as setBoss_Time is a string while this applies to an int. should modifying my getter/setter fix this?

Comment: @Baegmon There, it's fixed! See the changes? It is now, `((Boss) adapter.getItem(i)).setBoss_time(bossTime[i]);`

Comment: Yep I've just tested the code and it seems to work fine. May I ask if my logic is correct? Firstly create the object (what I was doing was repeating the object creation hence multiple objects). Then create a handler to repeatedly get a time and setting it using the forloop inside the run method?